# Alternatives to C calling convention? Good Resources? Advantages / Disadvantages?

Tags: language-agnostic, assembly, calling-convention

I'm really only familiar with the C calling convention at this time (as described at [Nasm - C calling convention](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.4.3)).  This same source also describes a Pascal style calling convention.

I am seeking to understand the various function calling conventions out there (description or sources)?  Also what are the advantages or disadvantages of using one over another (if any)?

NOTE:  Most interested in the x86 platform, but you're welcome to describe others.

Comment: Add the tags you are interested in. Probably Pascal too.

Comment: @Mahesh: I wouldn't add tags that hint at languages, when this is about calling conventions.

Comment: @Mahesh: I don't know. My suggestion would be to remove the C tag and add assembly / language-agnostic

Comment: @NiklasB: I am not so sure `assembly` fits, but I added them anyway.

Comment: @sbi: I think calling conventions are only really relevant if you're coding assembly, otherwise the compiler will handle it for you (or you need to do it yourself in inline assembly). OP also mentions NASM. Thanks for editing.

Comment: @NiklasB.:  Essentially the goal is to replicate them in assembly yes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: Following Ignacio's link leads to [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) .  This seems to sufficiently answer my own question, but it will be good to see what anyone else has to say.

Comment: BTW, if anyone is interested in this topic there is a nice write-up at http://www.agner.org/optimize/ under "Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big advantages to the C calling convention are:

1. handling of varargs. With the C calling convention, the caller pushes onto the stack and takes off -- and the caller knows how many arguments they passed, since they're doing the passing. Otherwise the callee has to figure it out somehow. They do anyway, of course, if they want to *use* the varargs, but why give them the chance to smash the stack if they get it wrong? Thus, languages that have the callee clean up tend not to support varargs.
2. your code is link-compatible with C (and most C++). You don't hear about glibpascal much, do you? Didn't think so.

Register based calling is useful too, and I think many C compilers do this to optimize rather than pushing integers/pointers on to the stack -- but not for externally-visible functions in libraries, of course!

The whole point about conventions is that they're *conventional*. It makes sense to follow the convention because then other people who obey the convention know what to expect. So really, don't overthink it. This is a case where following the crowd yields tangible benefits.

Comment: There's also the caller stack cleanup vs. callee stack cleanup discussion with the latter sometimes resulting in shorter code.

Comment: You mean because you can do "ret 12" rather than "ret" and then "add esp, 12"? Yes -- but I can't remember the last time I really wanted to save an opcode. Can you? (Genuinely curious -- maybe there are cases when people still do care about these things?)

Comment: I think the argument was that if you cleanup the stack in the callee, you don't need to replicate the cleanup code everywhere you call the function. Of course this is not much of an issue and `cdecl` goes a different approach, but this is one of the differences. In embedded systems, this might be a factor to consider.

Comment: Whoops, of course :-) Still a minor difference but makes sense now.

Comment: Pretty much every ABI save for x86 puts arguments on registers. Even x86-64 uses registers.